# Problem with Environment.StackTrace

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

On a thread that is processing new data in the system, if the data is invalid I write a message in the event log, containing the `Environment.StackTrace` information.

Writing in the event log throws an exception with no text message

```
Message: 
CallStack -    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
       at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
       at <my method that writes in the event log>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT: I am interested in what can cause the Environment.StackTrace to throw exception in general, so that i can understand what is happening in my case

Comment: Can you post the code that writes to the event log and that uses `Environment.StackTrace`?

Comment: The call to `Environment.StackTrace` is throwing an exception, while you are logging the message. Can you post enough code?

Comment: @leppie Yes, it is on a separate thread.

@Oded I can't really post more code, i am interested more in what can cause the Environment.StackTrace to throw exception

Answer (score 3):

@anchandra I don't know if you have figured this out since, as this is now 4 years old.

However I would like to add as I just stumbled upon this myself.

So, why does Environment.StackTrace throws an exception?

First the most uninteresting answer:
As you can see in the MSDN reference to the property, it can throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if "The requested stack trace information is out of range.", note also that the executing context must have System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission.

Now what stumped me for a second:
It does NOT throw an exception! Yes, that is what was happening to me, it actually returned me a Stack Trace that started listing the call to Environment.StackTrace like "at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()" then it showed all the other calling methods.
Because I was logging this into an audit log, if you look at it you assume there is an exception occurring at the last frame of the stack, but that's not true, I was just happening to request a Stack Trace at that point and stick it in my error log, very dumb once I realized this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the stacktrace before moving onto a separate thread.

`Stacktrace` will only show you the frames up to the root of the thread.

Comment: Yes, I will only see the frames of the thread, but why does it throw exception?